# Нет ли речевой избыточности в словосочетании "Обязательными нормами"?

Tags: тавтология, речевая-избыточность

В нашей ИТ-инфраструктуре соблюдение порядка и аккуратность считаются обязательными нормами.

Comment: Цель высказывания? На какой вопрос вы отвечаете?

Answer (score 1):

Если имеется в виду общепринятая социальная норма, то я бы написал:

> **В нашей ИТ-инфраструктуре соблюдение порядка и аккуратность считаются нормой.**

Если же имеются в виду некие внутренние **нормативы** (например, *корпоративные кодексы*, *правила поведения*), я бы написал:

> **В нашей ИТ-инфраструктуре соблюдение порядка и аккуратность являются
> обязательными нормами.**

Во этом варианте слово ***«считаются»*** было бы менее уместно, т.к. оно скорее подразумевает некие негласные, неформальные традиции. При этом речевой избыточности нет, так как нормы могут быть ***общепринятыми***, ***социальными***, ***условными*** и т.д.